# react native - How to pass JSX to swift?

Tags: swift, react-native, bridge

I used react-native-directed-view, but react-native-directed-view became unmaintained.

I success to use `UIScrollView` in react native and to pass variable to native code.

below is part of my code. I use `requireNativeComponent` to bridge.

```
import {
  ...
  requireNativeComponent
} from 'react-native'
const CounterView = requireNativeComponent("CounterView")
...
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CounterView />
    </View>
  )
}
```

BUT!!!

I can't use `porps.children`(HOC) in swift.
I can pass string and integer to swift, because obj-c has string and integer type.

```
@objc var count: NSSumber = 0
```

However there is no jsx type in obj-c

How to create HOC with swift?
react-native-directed-view used HOC with objective-c.
I want to use HOC with swift.

I know using `RCTRootView` in swift enable to use jsx in swift.
I want to know how to pass JSX and how to use it with `RCTRootView`.

Ideal code is below.

```
import {View, Text, requireNativeComponent}
const UIscrollView = requireNativeComponent("UIScrollView")

// HOC with native code
const App = () => (
  <UIScrollView height={100} width={100}>
    <View>
      <Text>lol</Text>
    </View>
  <UIScrollView>
)

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you link this libs to native code. I mean react-native link react-native-directed-view.

Comment: react-native-directed-view has a lot of bug.
I need create new one. thanks.